# Windows 10 free upgrade: best way to "get now, use later"?

Tags: windows-10

I'm getting ready to deploy a couple dozen new PCs running Windows 7 Pro (OEM) in a small-biz environment. Many of their applications are old, and they still run Server 2003 (for now), so they're not ready to make the jump to Windows 10 yet. Still, I'd like to secure these machines' free Windows 10 upgrades if possible, for use once the time is right.

My understanding is that a machine must complete the upgrade and activate in order to be listed in Microsoft's registration database, which then entitles it to have Windows 10 reinstalled and freely activated in the future. Correct?

If so, what's the easiest way of getting 20-some-odd machines over this hurdle, and back again?

Must I install (or deploy from our image, as it were) Windows 7, perform the Windows 10 upgrade, activate, wipe the machine, and then re-deploy the Windows 7 image - for EVERY machine? Or is there an easier way (ie. boot each machine from a drive with Windows 10 installed, let it complain about activation, re-activate, and be done)?

If it can't be done in a reasonable fashion, oh well. But it would be nice to save $2K or so in licensing fees should we decide to make the move in a year or two.

Comment: Unfortunately, enterprise hardware or software questions are off-topic here—please try [sf] instead. See the [help/on-topic] for details. (Please don't cross-post—if you post your question there, you should delete the question here.)

Comment: Because the free upgrade “consumes” the Windows 7 license, this is not a good idea. While it may be possible to get Windows 7 to activate again, there may be issues activating the archived Windows 10 installation in the future. Also, there’s still time. ;)

Comment: Aye. also win7 computers may be older. And replacement HW may already come with win 10 for free.  (Free as in: you pay more).

Comment: The free upgrade does not consume the license that is upgraded....I should know have the license I used for one upgrade on a cloned virtual machine both installations are activated.  I have read the EULA I am not in violation.

Comment: @Ramhound Actually, the EULA doesn’t say a single thing about this. Of course, if you feel that I’m wrong, invite me to chat and point out the exact sections that grant additional use of an upgrade “base license”.

Comment: Right; EULA does not indicate the license is consumed;

Answer (score 1):

As I understood it with 10 *consumer* licences: Yes. You need to do that.

For larger corporation you usually would get an enterprise edition of the OS, which has lots of nice features but which can not be upgrade for free. For that you need to buy windows 10 (regular or enterprise).

The big question here is: Can you afford to buy win 10 enterprise? If you can then buy those licences when you need it and leave the current setup alone.

If you are on a shoestring budget then:

1. Make a full backup of each computer (or replace the harddisk and make a clean windows 7 install).
2. Individually upgrade each PC to windows 10.
3. Replace the HDD or restore from backup.

This would be cheap (moneywise), but in effect you are paying with a lot of work hours.

My advice: Leave the current PCs as is and see if you can budget for legal licences, both for windows 10 enterprise (for when you need it) and windows server (as soon as possible).